# How to increase the AWS Cognito Access Token Validity one hour to one day in Amazon Cognito User Pools

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am facing token expire issue every 20 to 40 mins but actual time is one hour but I need a token validity one day.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to change the token validity period with AWS Cognito User Pools. Currently, its fixed to 1 hour.